# Logic Puzzle (Valid and Invalid Arguments)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I have been given a logic puzzle and I am having a tough time figuring out how to set it up and solve. Here is the puzzle: 
a) **The Statement "If Dr. Jones did not commit the murder then neither Ms. Scarlet nor Mr. Green committed the murder" is false.** I interpret that as: $$ \lnot D \to (\lnot S \lor \lnot G)$$ 
Now isn't the ONLY way for conditional statements to be false is if the hypothesis is true and the condition is false? Thus leaving $ \lnot D $

 b) **Either Mr.Green did not commit the murder or the weapon was a candlestick.** I read that as: $$ \lnot G\lor C $$
c) **If the weapon was a candlestick then Dr. Jones commited the murder.** That reads $$ C \to D $$
Question is who committed the murder?
The thing that I am having most trouble with is figuring out what laws to use in order to solve this. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: slight misstep in step one.  what does it say if he did commit the murders?

Comment: There is no misstep. If Dr. Jones had in fact committed the murder, there is no way for the implication to become false, because in **that** case the implication really says **nothing**.

Comment: You know two things from (a), though... and your formulatoin is slightly wrong: "neither Ms. Scarlet nor Mr. Green" is logically "not (Scarlett or Green)" which is "(not Scarlett) and (not Green)"

Answer (score 2):

The correct interpretation of statement a is

$$\lnot (\lnot D \to (\lnot S \land \lnot G))$$ which is equivalent to $$\lnot D \land (S \lor G)$$. This means $S$ or $G$ committed the murder, not the Dr.; and by the contrapositive of c, that the candlestick was not used in the murder. Then by b, $S$ is responsible.

Comment: Nice answer, although you might want to explain the last part a bit more.

Comment: The candlestick was not used, so Mr Green is not responsible by b. By the deduction for a, this means S is responsible.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the method you used in step A to conclude that information.

Comment: I encoded statement a as follows: NOT (IF NOT dr Jones THEN (NOT ms Scarlet AND NOT Mr Green))

Answer (score 0):

Your deductions so far are correct, and you already know Dr. Jones did not commit the murder. Condition (c) then tells you the weapon was not a candlestick, and finally condition (b) tells you who committed the murder (since the other alternative, "the murder weapon was a candlestick", has already been shown to be false).